# Controller 'masonry', required by directive 'ngSwitch', can't be found

Tags: angularjs, masonry

Here are my html:

```
<div masonry id="graphicGridDiv">
    <div class="masonry-brick" ng-switch on="{{graphic.length}}" ng-repeat="graphic in graphicArray">

        <div ng-switch-when="1" class="col-sm-4 gra-mix-graphic ">
            <div class="category_1 custom-menu-preview mix" ng-click="singleGraContent(graphic[0].id)">
                <p class="video_title" title="title" ng-bind="$parent.graphic[0].name"></p>

                <div class="gra-mix-inner">
                    <img ng-src="{{$parent.graphic[0].src}}" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="caption">
                    <p class="video_detail" title="digest" ng-bind="$parent.graphic[0].digest"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="gra-mix-details-t">
                    <a class="mix-link but" title="delete" ng-click="graDelete($parent.graphic[0].id)">
                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a class="mix-preview but fancybox-button" title="edit" ng-click="graEdit(graphic[0])" >
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-default class="col-sm-4 gra-mix-graphic">
            <div class="gra-mix-details-t">
                <a class="mix-link" title="delete" ng-click="graDelete(id)">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="gra-mix-preview fancybox-button" ng-click="graEdit(id)" title="edit**strong text**" data-rel="fancybox-button">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="category_1 custom-menu-preview" ng-click="multiGraContent(id)">
                <div class="gra-mix-inner thumbnail">
                    <img ng-src="{{graphic[0].src}}" class="img-responsive" style="width: 330px;">

                </div>
                <div class="multiFirstTitle">
                    <p class="video_sub_title"  title="{{graphic[0].name}}" ng-bind="graphic[0].name"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="multi" ng-repeat="mutiGra in graphic | arrayLimitFilter:1 ">
                    <p title="{{mutiGra.name}}" ng-bind="mutiGra.name" class="video_artical_title"></p>

                    <div class="multiImage" id="multiImageDiv">
                        <img ng-src="{{mutiGra.src}}" class="multiImage">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is the actual error text:

> ```
> at Object.$watchCollectionAction [as fn]  <div class="masonry-brick ng-scope" ng-switch="" on="{{graphic.length}}"
> ```
>
> ng-repeat="graphic in graphicArray">

Answer (score 0):

ng-controller is not specified anywhere in your HTML. Assuming your controller is named masonry you need to add ng-controller="masonry" to your outer div.